# Overloading std::transform algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, transform, std

Consider this standard use of std::transform algorithm:

```
vector<int> in = { 1, 2, 3 };
auto f0 = [](int val) { return val + 1; };
auto f1 = [](int val) { return val > 1; };

vector<int> out0(in.size()); 
std::transform(in.begin(), in.end(), out0.begin(), f0);
vector<bool> out1(in.size()); 
std::transform(in.begin(), in.end(), out1.begin(), f1);
```

This works fine but is long to write. I would like to write something like this:

```
auto out0 = tranform(in, f0);
auto out1 = tranform(in, f1);
```

How to overload the transform algorithm to allow this syntax?

Comment: It is not necessary to declare the sizes. Use std::back_inserter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do what you want

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template<typename T, typename F>
std::vector<typename std::result_of<F(T)>::type>
transform(const std::vector<T>& l, F func)
{
    typedef typename std::result_of<F(T)>::type FunctorReturnType;
    std::vector<FunctorReturnType> out(l.size());
    std::transform(l.begin(), l.end(), out.begin(), func);
    return out;
}

int main ()
{
    const std::vector<int> in{ 1, 2, 3 };
    auto f0 = [](int val) { return val + 1; };
    auto f1 = [](int val) { return val > 1; };

    auto out0 = transform(in, f0);
    auto out1 = transform(in, f1);

    for (const auto& m: out0) std::cout << m << std::endl;
    for (const auto& m: out1) std::cout << m << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This actually does not compile but works fine with this header : transform(const vector<T>& l, F func) -> vector<decltype(func(T{}))>

Comment: I downvoted. I took more time actually trying out your code than you. You are not even trying to use the mess of your trasnform, you are just invoking std::transform from your main().

Comment: @DanielKO thanks for letting me know. My bad, sorry, I'm trying to get my code working.

Comment: That solution assumes that `FunctorReturnType` is default constructible... else you **have** to use `back_inseter`.

Answer (score 2):

Do you like template template arguments? This works with more containers than vectors.

```
template<template<class...> class C, class F, class T, class... Tail>
C<typename result_of<F(T)>::type>
transform(const C<T, Tail...>& in, F func)
{
    C<typename result_of<F(T)>::type> out(in.size());
    std::transform(in.begin(), in.end(), out.begin(), func);
    return out;
}
```

Can be seen working at http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/767adb662d7cbe42

EDIT: changed to not use the source's allocator in the resulting container.

Comment: You may have some strange things as you use original allocator in the result container without rebind it to the new type...

Comment: That solution assumes that `result_of<F(T)>::type` is default constructible... else you have to use `std::back_inserter`.

Comment: Indeed, all STL implementations I know rebind the provided allocator, but I couldn't find any word about it in the standard. It might be safer to use a default allocator.

Comment: And about default-constructible, I followed the skeleton of the code supplied, that's why I didn't bother to make the trivial change to use a `back_inserter`. No point posting this on every answer when it was already commented on the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you ok with the following, which doesn't use any C++11 magic such as `decltype` ?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
template<class T, class F>
std::vector<T> transform(const std::vector<T>& l, F func)
{
  std::vector<T> out(l.size());
  std::transform(l.begin(), l.end(), out.begin(), func);
  return out;
}
```

Comment: That's because he's trying to use `auto` to create a container..which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: shouldn't it be `std::vector<T>` ?
just replace `auto` with `std::vector<T>` ...don't see any reason to use `auto` here..

Comment: @hivert looks like he wants the return type of the function he passed.. the question was poorly written..

Comment: @KoKuToru And demonstrates a fundamental misunderstanding of C++11 concepts.

Comment: You cannot return vector<T> because the function can return any other type.